# Lambda machine-dependent segmentation-fault (possible compiler bug?)

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, g++, segmentation-fault

Today I came across a very strange bug. I created a minimal example:

https://gist.github.com/SuperV1234/5792381

Basically, on some machines, "test 2" segfaults; on others, it works as intended.
On my desktop computer it works, both on Windows 8 x64 and Linux Mint 15 x64.
On my laptop computer it segfaults, both on Windows 8 x64 and Linux Mint 15 x64.

What puzzles me is:

- the fact that it works on some machines and crashes on other machines
- the fact that simply wrapping the lambda contents in another function fixes the segfault

Is this a compiler bug? Or is there a difference between `Game::test1()` and the lambda body?

```
// Test 1 works
// Test 2 segfaults... on some machines.
// Compiled with -std=c++11, GCC 4.8.1, tested both on native Linux, Windows and Wine

#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Command
{
    function<void()> func;
    void reset() { }
};

struct Timeline
{
    vector<Command*> commands;
    void clear() 
    {
        for(auto& c : commands) delete c;
        commands.clear();
    }
    void reset() { for(auto& c : commands) c->reset(); }
};

struct Game
{
    Timeline timeline;

    void test1() { timeline.clear(); timeline.reset(); }
    void run()
    {
        {
            cout << "Starting test 1..." << endl;

            Command* cmd{new Command};
            cmd->func = [&]{ test1(); };
            timeline.commands.push_back(cmd); cmd->func();

            cout << "Successfully ending test 1..." << endl;
        }

        {
            cout << "Starting test 2..." << endl;

            Command* cmd{new Command};
            cmd->func = [&]{ timeline.clear(); timeline.reset(); };
            timeline.commands.push_back(cmd); cmd->func();

            cout << "Successfully ending test 2..." << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() { Game{}.run(); return 0; }
```

Real code (not a minimal example) is available here: https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVOpenHexagon/commit/77784ae142768f964666afacfeed74300501ec07

Backtrace from real code: http://paste2.org/W7yeCxOO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the disassembly, the first lambda looks like this:

```
      test1();
mov         eax,dword ptr [this]  
mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
call        Game::test1 (021717h)
```

The first two lines get the address of the captured `Game` object and pass it to the `Game::test1`.

The second lambda looks like this:

```
      timeline.clear();
mov         eax,dword ptr [this]  
mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
call        Timeline::clear (08415D2h)  
      timeline.reset(); 
mov         eax,dword ptr [this]  
mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
call        Timeline::reset (08416D6h)
```

The problem here is that after `timeline.clear` the lambda is destroyed and the second attempt to get the captured `Game` object puts some garbage in `ecx`. As a result of that, `Timeline::reset` gets called with an invalid pointer.

Edit: your lambdas are basically this:

```
struct lambda_1 {
    Game* game;
    void operator()() {
        game->test1();
    }
};

struct lambda_2 {
    Game* game;
    void operator()() {
        game->timeline.clear();
        game->timeline.reset();
    }
};
```

So what happens is that you're trying to access a member of a deleted object.

Comment: Thanks, easy to understand and well written. Any idea why it didn't segfault on some machines?

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo afaik accessing member of a deleted object leads to an undefined behaviour, so anything can happen. My guess is that it worked for you in the release configuration. In release deleted objects doesn't usually get overwritten with garbage data immediately.

Comment: actually, I tested the same exact release executable and the same exact debug executable (I had everything in a .7z archive) on different machines (laptop and desktop, both running dual boot Linux Mint and Windows 8). The desktop never segfaulted (even after reboots), the laptop always did, with both operating systems. Maybe I'll never discover the reason this happened, but it's still kind of interesting

Answer (score 3):

You are deleting the lambda while it is being run. I don't think it is a sane thing to do.

Your code is somewhat equivalent to this:

```
Command *c = new Command;
c->func = [&] { delete c; };
c->fun();
```

If you really need to do something like this, you may copy the function before calling it:

```
Command *c = new Command;
c->func = [&] { delete c; };
auto f = c->func; //copy the function
f();  //c->func is deleted, but f is not!
```

PS: You are aware that your `clear` / `reset` thing, as it is, makes little sense, aren't you?

Comment: You mean the clear/reset thing in the example? If so, obviously yes :) 
I was trying to mimic the "real code".